After update to Kubuntu 22.04 some apps, require `--no-sandbox` flag
Examples of such apps: Shadow PC, FreeTube. I gues those are Electron-based apps.
Without this flag I get:
[54535:0428/103432.837815:FATAL:credentials.cc(125)] Check failed: . : Access denied (13)


BTW: what a shame. I've used (k)ubuntu for almost 20 years, and never had major update issues, even with development version. Now it's 3rd issue I'm putting on AskUbuntu. It seems quality dropped terribly in Canonical. Those are obvious bugs, it seems nobody even tested it!

I find this solution on the Internet a few days ago and it's a problem related to apparmor. You can try this command:
sudo sysctl -w kernel.apparmor_restrict_unprivileged_userns=0

It need to be run again after rebooting.
